# Как вставить текст напротив каждой диаграммы?

Tags: css, flexbox

Нужна помощь по css , как вставить текст черный с задним фоном для каждой гистограммы ,чтоб одступы одинаковые были и находились возле каждой диаграммы не сьезжая при масштабировании ? Можно пример какой-то пожалуйста ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сделал чтоб в столбик текст выводило и закрашивало текст https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLxBo  , но вот только фон для текста одинаковый ,как сделать разный цвет ?**

```
 <div class="flex-container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">ЧО-1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">ЧО-2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">ЧО-3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">ЧО-4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">ЧО-5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item">ЧО-6</span>
  </div>
</div>




.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;

}

row{
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;

  line-height: 70px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Предоставьте код, пожалуйста.

Comment: вот ссылка на код http://jsfiddle.net/zdq9xLoa/2/

Comment: только мне тоже самое но текст отдельно css-ом

Answer (score -1):

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

row {
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item" style="background: #FFA500;">ЧО-1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item" style="background: #7CFC00;">ЧО-2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item" style="background: #00FFFF;">ЧО-3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item" style="background:  #4169E0;">ЧО-4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item" style="background: #008080;">ЧО-5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="flex-item" style="background: #2F4F4F;">ЧО-6</span>
  </div>
</div>
```